# Pass a variable that contains a comma as a -v option to qsub

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, brace-expansion, qsub

After seeing the reactions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616176/pass-a-variable-that-contains-a-comma-as-a-v-option-to-qsub) on this question and an unfamiliarity with qsub, I believe thqt U&L is better suited for this question.

In qsub, we can pass environment variables (a comma-separated list of `envar=value` pairs) like so:

```bash
info="This is some info"
qsub -v INFO=$info script.pbs
```

However, this becomes problematic when $info contains a comma.

```bash
info="This is some info, and here is some more!"
qsub -v INFO=$info script.pbs
```

This will trigger an error like so:

> ERROR: `-v`: variable '  and here is some more!' is not set in environment variables.

I have also tried encapsuling `info`, `INFO="$info"` leading to the same issue.

How can I pass `$info` correctly, even if it contains one or more commas? The same question holds with newlines which always end up incorrectly when they are passed (backslash gets removed).

Perhaps an interesting observation is that when I `echo -e $info` I get the output that I expect. The error is triggered in the `qsub` command specifically.

Comment: If you're on Bash, that unquoted `INFO=$info` will get word-split, likely making `is`, `some` etc. taken as filenames. The result should be quite different with and without the quotes.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76616176/7552

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, I made that explicit at the start.

Comment: In that case, please delete the instance over at stackoverflow. Cross-posting is strongly discouraged in the SE network and will lead to close-votes.

Comment: At the very least, link to it so people who want to answer here can see what has already been talked about there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid this problem by giving only the variable name on the command line (which is visible to the command):

```
export INFO="This is some info, and here is some more!"
qsub -v INFO script.pbs
```

or

```
INFO="This is some info, and here is some more!" qsub -v INFO script.pbs
```

Answer (score -4):

```
qsub -v INFO="$info" script.pbs
```